Getting error: "No provider of glGetTexImage found." using gtk4 on Raspberry Pi 4
I am writing a new version of my digital media frame code for the pi4 (Raspbian 12) using gtk4. You can download the code and test it out with the following commands:
git clone https://github.com/najoshi/nik-presents.git
python3 nik-presents/pi4/nik_presents_pi4.py --jsonfile nik-presents/pi4/test/test.json --mediadir nik-presents/pi4/test --duration 3 --verbose

So I am getting the following error after the first video plays:
No provider of glGetTexImage found. Requires one of    
    Desktop OpenGL 1.0    
Aborted

Images seem to work fine.... it's just the video to image transition that is giving errors. What is really frustrating is that this code works just fine on my Ubuntu desktop. The renderer class for mpv I got from https://github.com/trin94/python-mpv-gtk4 . Any help would be highly appreciated.
